# Exemple about a set which is not connected but it's interior is connected

Tags: general-topology

As in the title i want to find a set $A$ from a topological space such that 
$$
A~\text{ is not connected but}~~ \rm int(A)~\text{ is connected} 
$$

i tryed with this space: $E=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ with $$\tau=\{\emptyset, E,\{b\},\{c\},\{b,c\},\{c,d\},\{b,c,d\}\}$$

$E$ is connected, $\{b,c,e\}$ is connected but it's interior no, but i don't find a set not connected but this interior connected.

Comment: $(0,1)\cup \{2\}$

Comment: Or even easier, $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Michael why $(0,1)\cup\{2\}$ is not connected, $(0,1)$ is open and $\{2\}$ is closed? also, can i find a such A with my example ? thank you very much

Comment: @PolineSandra But $(3/2,3)$ is an open set that is disjoint from $(0,1)$ and contains $2$.

Comment: @Michael i don't understand your argument  why you use (3/2,3) we say that set is connected if we can't write as the union of two open disjoint sets

Comment: @PolineSandra The open subsets of $(0,1)\cup \{2\}$ are by definition the sets of the form $A\cap(0,1)\cup \{2\}$, where $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. In our case, $\{2\}$ is an open subset of $(0,1)\cup \{2\}$, because for example $(3/2,3) \cap ((0,1)\cup \{2\})=\{2\}$.